# Cannot close an antd modal using reactJS library

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need your helps, when I do click those 3 buttons on the red circles, It threw an error that's called '... is not a function' though I think closing a modal needs an useState hook which set boolean to close it. Am I wrong? If I'm not wrong so how to solve it, please help me!~~~

[Images show error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coMyx.png)
[Images show error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ces8R.jpg)

Here is my code

```
import {createContext, useState, useContext, useMemo} from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from './AuthProvider'
import useFirestore  from '../hooks/useFirestore'

export const AppContext = createContext()

function AppProvider ({children}) {
    const [isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible] = useState(false)
    const user = useContext(AuthContext)
    
    const {uid} = user

    const roomsCondition = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            fieldName: 'members',
            operator: 'array-contains',
            value: uid
        }
    }, [uid])

    const rooms = useFirestore('rooms', roomsCondition)

    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={[rooms, isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible]}>
            {children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AppProvider
```

```
import {Modal, Form, Input} from 'antd'
import { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { AppContext } from '../../Context/AppProvider'
import { AuthContext } from '../../Context/AuthProvider'
import { addDocument } from '../../firebase/service'


export default function AddRoomModal() {
    const [isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible] = useContext(AppContext)
    const user = useContext(AuthContext)

    const {uid} = user;

    const [form] = Form.useForm()
    const handleOk = () => {
        // console.log({
        //     formData: form.getFieldsValue()
        // })
        addDocument('rooms', {...form.getFieldsValue(), members: [uid]})
        setIsAddRoomVisible(false)
    }

    const handleCancel = () => {
        setIsAddRoomVisible(false)
    }
        return (
        <div>
            <Modal
                title="Create room"
                visible={isAddRoomVisible}
                onOk={handleOk}
                okCancel={handleCancel}
            >
                <Form form={form} layout="vertical">
                    <Form.Item label="Room's name" name="name">
                        <Input placeholder="Enter room's name here"/>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item label="Description" name="description">
                        <Input.TextArea placeholder="Enter description"/>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't the first row of AddRoomModal be :

```
const [room, isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible] = useContext(AppContext)
```

You are destructuring an array not an object, so you cannot skip any element of the value prop of your context

EDIT :
Ok so i'll try to give you more info.

The first thing I notice is you are using a difficult way to handle your modal using a context. it would be easier to include your component in another that will contain the opening button and the modal open state :

```
const ModalParent = () => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalOpen(true)}>openModal</button>
      <Modal
        title="Create room"
        visible={isModalOpen}
        onOk={(e) => {
          setIsModalOpen(false);
        }}
        okCancel={(e) => {
          setIsModalOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        Hi my Modal !
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

But you can still use the context approach, it allows you to control your modal from anywhere in your app, which can be pretty useful.

When you are using your context provider, you are passing it an array containing three values :

```
<AppContext.Provider value={[rooms, isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible]}>
```

When you are using the useContext hook, you are retrieving this array in your component.

```
const myAppContextValues = useContext(AppContext)
const rooms = myAppContextValues[0]
const isAddRoomVisible = myAppContextValues[1]
const setIsAddRoomVisible= myAppContextValues[2]
```

In you're case, you are using a syntax to define more quickly variables from an array called destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment .
But you are skipping an element of the array.

So if we translate your code in vanilla JS you are actually doing :

```
// Here you are retrieving the element 0 & 1 and putting them in variable isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible
// const [isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible] = useContext(AppContext)
// Under is the vanilla JS example
const myAppContextValues = useContext(AppContext)
const isAddRoomVisible = myAppContextValues[0]
const setIsAddRoomVisible= myAppContextValues[1]
```

So what you need to do is to also assign the room element, even if you don't use it

```
const [room, isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible] = useContext(AppContext)
```

You could also use an object as value of your context and destructuring it with the object syntax :

```
  // notice that here i'm using the shorthand syntax to create an object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015
  <AppContext.Provider value={{rooms, isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible}}>
 // and here i'm using the object destructuring
  const {isAddRoomVisible, setIsAddRoomVisible} = useContext(AppContext)
```

Hope it helps you and it is clearer !

Comment: hmmm so what can i do now? replace the array to object? because I tried some times putting an object It threw errors x_x